# Swagger getting struck when returning Microsoft.Graph.User return type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

I have a default .NET 6 WebAPI project generated by VisualStudio to which I have added Microsoft.Graph nuget package

[image]

Here is my program.cs

[image]

and finally my controller

[image]

When I run this project and try to test the Get endpoint, the swagger UI is getting struck and there is no error being thrown

[image]

If I change the return type to either dynamic or object, it works as expected. Maybe I overlooking something basic but I couldn't figure out this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors on the Console and Network tabs in the browser dev tools?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the Dev tools or VS Diagnostics tools or Event viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speedup rendering for complex types like `Microsoft.Graph.User` by disabling syntax highlight.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
{
    config.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems["syntaxHighlight"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["activated"] = false
    };
});
```

With this setting UI gets stuck only for 10-15 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me pinpoint the issue. I didn't realize Microsoft.Graph.User is such a complex object which should not be returned as is. I will map this to an output model with the fields that I need.